# Sharepoint 2010 reformatting person/group field data

Tags: field-controls

We have a site where our survey for employee nominations and our nominee field uses the Person/Group field to capture the name.

[image]
 The field already has an automatic option that you click to lookup the user entered and verifies it.  Once verified the name is formatted into LastName, FirstName, Middle.

[image]
Is there a way to reformat the users name after it has been verified to be:  FirstName Middle LastName?

Answer (score 1):

The value displayed here comes from the "Name" (or "PreferredName") property for the user in the User Profile Service Application.  If you are syncing with Active Directory (or another directory service) the value comes from there.  In order to change how it is displayed, you would need to change the value in the directory service and then run a full profile sync in SharePoint.